# Find first occurrence of Price value which is greater than current value in Pandas dataframe using vectorization

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

lets take this example Pandas dataframe which has two columns `'date'` and `'price'` where `'date'` is always ascending and `'price'` is random, i.e.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date':['01/01/2019', '01/02/2019', '01/03/2019',
            '01/04/2019', '01/05/2019', '01/06/2019', 
            '01/07/2019', '01/08/2019', '01/09/2019', 
            '01/10/2019'],
    'price': [10, 2, 5, 4, 12, 8, 9, 19, 12, 3]
})
```

The goal is to add two more columns, `'next_date'` and `'next_price'` where
`'next_date'` contains the date of the first occurrence of a price which is greater than current price and `'next_price'` contains the price of the first occurrence of a price which is greater than current price, i.e.

```
         date  price   next_date next_price
0  01/01/2019     10  01/05/2019         12
1  01/02/2019      2  01/03/2019          5
2  01/03/2019      5  01/05/2019         12
3  01/04/2019      4  01/05/2019         12
4  01/05/2019     12  01/08/2019         19
5  01/06/2019      8  01/07/2019          9
6  01/07/2019      9  01/08/2019         19
7  01/08/2019     19         NaN        NaN
8  01/09/2019     12         NaN        NaN
9  01/10/2019      3         NaN        NaN
```

I have tested some solutions which did what I want but with very poor performance and since the real dataframe contains over a million rows, they are impractical.

These are my test solutions:

Using Pandasql

```
result = sqldf("SELECT l.date, l.price, min(r.date) as next_date " +
               "from df as l left join df as r on (r.date > l.date " + 
               "and r.price > l.price) group by l.date, l.price  order by l.date")
result = pd.merge(result ,df, left_on='next_date', right_on='date', 
                  suffixes=('', '_next'), how='left')
print(result)
```

Using Pandas to SQLite

```
df.to_sql('df', conn, index=False)
qry = "SELECT l.date, l.price, min(r.date) as next_date from df as " + 
      "l left join df as r on (r.date > l.date and r.price > l.price) " + 
      "group by l.date, l.price  order by l.date"
result = pd.read_sql_query(qry, conn)
result = pd.merge(result ,df, left_on='next_date', right_on='date', 
                  suffixes=('', '_next'), how='left')
print(result)
```

Using `apply`

```
def find_next_price(row):
    mask = (df['price'] > row['price']) & (df['date'] > row['date'])
    if len(df[mask]):
        return df[mask]['date'].iloc[0], df[mask]['price'].iloc[0]
    else:
        return np.nan, np.nan

df[['next_date', 'next_price']] = list(df.apply(find_next_price, axis=1))
print(df)
```

Some of these solutions start to fail with as few as 50,000 rows,
While I need to perform this task on a million rows.

Note:
there is a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72047646/python-pandas-add-column-containing-first-index-where-future-column-value-is-gr) but the performance of the answers is still insufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you need to perform this task on large number of rows (1M+), a traditional approach with `numpy` might not be feasible especially when you limited amount of memory. Here I'm presenting a functional approach using basic algorithmic computation and you can compile this function with `numba's` just in time compiler to achieve `C` like speeds:

```
import numba

@numba.njit
def argmax(price: np.ndarray):
    for i in range(len(price)):
        idx = -1
        for j in range(i + 1, len(price)):
            if price[i] < price[j]:
                idx = j
                break

        yield idx
        idx = -1


i = np.array(list(argmax(df['price'].values)))
m = i != -1 # index is -1 if there's no next greater price

df.loc[m, 'next_date'] = df['date'].values[i[m]]
df.loc[m, 'next_price'] = df['price'].values[i[m]]
```

Result

```
         date  price   next_date  next_price
0  01/01/2019     10  01/05/2019        12.0
1  01/02/2019      2  01/03/2019         5.0
2  01/03/2019      5  01/05/2019        12.0
3  01/04/2019      4  01/05/2019        12.0
4  01/05/2019     12  01/08/2019        19.0
5  01/06/2019      8  01/07/2019         9.0
6  01/07/2019      9  01/08/2019        19.0
7  01/08/2019     19         NaN         NaN
8  01/09/2019     12         NaN         NaN
9  01/10/2019      3         NaN         NaN
```

**PS: Solution is tested on 1M+ rows.**

Comment: it is good and fast indeed, thanks a lot.

Comment: My upvote. But I m sure you know you can make it even faster if you can find the next greater element using a stack like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30289575/greatest-element-present-on-the-right-side-of-every-element-in-an-array)